# JSON reading error on C#

Tags: c#, json, windows-8

I am getting an error on my Windows 8 App on a particular page on my app.

> Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: <.
>   Path ", line 2, position 1.

I have other pages on my App that uses JSON and they work fine, but when I get to this page I get this json error.

The actual C# code in my touch app:

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://test.com/products/?category=" + (String)navigationParameter);



        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {


            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var data= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);

        }

        else
        {
            MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog("Error");
            await dlg.ShowAsync();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorMessage = ex.Message;
    }

    if (errorMessage != string.Empty)
    {
        MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog(errorMessage + " \nError here.");
        await dlg.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

I can't seem to identify what's wrong here. I'm not sure what changed because this code worked fine on the app, until I just noticed it stopped working now.

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code in future - and ideally show us a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. You should be able to take the broken JSON and reduce it down to a short example that could be included directly in the code, without any fetching from the web site. Additionally, you haven't told us where the problem occurs.

Comment: Have you inspected the value of the content variable?...and yeah, do not expect users to navigate unsolicited websites named "naughty..something"

Comment: @JonSkeet Noted. In terms of the error, That's just it, I can;t identify where this error is happening. Unless you mean at what point in the app. In that case, I get this error in a dialogue box when I try to navigate to a product screen in my app, which should show the some of the json data structured

Comment: @Tester: Well presumably you're catching the exception in your catch block... but then you're throwing away all the information other than the message. Don't do that - log the whole exception, including the stack trace. You should *also* be able to find out where it's going wrong using a debugger.

Comment: @PeterLillevold what are you referring to?

Comment: I'd recommend you download Fiddler and inspect the HTML + JSON travelling over the wire - this will give you much more information on where the error is creeping in. You hopefully will see the corrupt JSON and the call which causes it to be sent.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am using .NET to debug, but it doesn't find any errors, it launched the app successfully and then I get the error on screen when I navigate to that page

Comment: @Tester in your sample, you have one variable named content. Set a breakpoint before deserializing, and take a look at what you are trying to deserialize.

Comment: @PeterLillevold I set the breakpoint and the variable content is showing "null". But I checked on another page where it still works fine, and the content variable there shows up as null too. Just checked back, after I noticed a small error, and the content variable show all the json data, bit I still get the error on the app itself

Comment: You should step through with the debugger. That's my point. Execute the code line by line. And as I said, log the full exception rather than just displaying a dialog box with the exception message. You've *got* to get the hang of these basic diagnostic steps, otherwise every problem will be hard to fix.

Comment: @JonSkeet Okay. I'm going to do some more on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this xml-style comment at the end of the response:

```
<!-- Quick Cache is NOT caching this page, because `$_GET` contains query string data. The current configuration says NOT to cache GET requests with a query string. -->
```

So, your actual response is like that:

```
{ /* Some JSON object here */ }
<!-- XML comment here ?! -->
```

That is not valid I think. At least JsonConvert agrees with me :)

You better trim the last line, then you get a valid JSON.